# Can I create an ArrayList that contains TextViews and ImageViews in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, arraylist, view

I am making a small game, and at the end of each turn a summary of that turn is added as to a `String` called `gameSummary` which is then set as the text for a TextView at the bottom of the screen in a `ScrollView`.

However, I would like this summary to also show the images of the dice roll for each turn, so my current method of updating a `String` variable wouldn't work, so I was thinking of using an ArrayList that added an `ImageView` of the dice roll then a `TextView` of the turn summary. Is this possible? Or can anyone think of a better way around this?

Answer (score 0):

You can add Images inside the text of a `TextView`. These are called `Spannable`s. To do so you'll use [SpannableStringBuilder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder.html) and [ImageSpan](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ImageSpan.html). Example:

```
SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder("initial text");
builder.append("\n");
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), drawableId);
int imageIndex = builder.length();
builder.setSpan(new ImageSpan(context, image, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE),
                index , index+1, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
textView.setText(builder);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a new Class with which includes your image and text then make an ArrayList of that Class.  I would probably then use a ListView to display them.

(not tested)

```
public class TurnSummary {
    private String turnTextSummary;
    private Bitmap turnDiceImage;

    public TurnSummary(String summary, Bitmap image) {
        this.turnTextSummary = summary;
        this.turnDiceImage = image;
    }

    // getters & setters
}
```

Then creating a list would be:

```
List<TurnSummary> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new TurnSummary(summary, diceImage));
```